# How to use absolute path with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import, tsconfig

I have a project that written in Typescript on NodeJS. I am using relative path for my modules to import another. But this usage is getting dirty while project is growing. Because of that I want to convert relative paths to absolute path.

Here is my project folder structure:

```
src
├── controllers
├── repositories
├── services
│   ├── user.service.ts
|── tsconfig.json
```

I want to use import another module like below.

```
import userServices from "src/services/user.service";
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "*": ["src/*"]
}
```

Above configurations is not working on my workspace.

Could you help me about that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a **TypeScript** feature that allows this.

You can modify your `src/tsconfig.json` file to enable this, under `compilerOptions`, add the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./*",
        "app/*",
        "../node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
}
```

You can obviously change the pattern key and values as needed. You add or remove folders, you can change the order, etc.

You can also choose a prefix instead of just `*` (especially if it cases problems), you can use something like ~/*, and your imports will then be all from `'~/shared/sample'` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your tsconfig. Change the path as required by you

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not working with "baseUrl": "./" and "baseUrl": "./src".

Comment: I guess this will fail at compile time.